# How to expose IP of a VM to only authenticated users in GCP Project

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-authentication

The use case is the following:

- Private network for the GCP project
- VPN on the local computer that seems to be blocking SSH connections
- A VM that has a webapp to be accessed but we don't want to expose the IP to the public network

What are the best practices to keep it private and to access it eg. with OAuth authentication?
What are the steps to make and to follow?

Appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods in Google Cloud. The second method is the recommended method based upon the requirements in your question.

1. If the users have defined public IP addresses, use Google Cloud [VPC firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) to only allow access from approved IP addresses.
2. Do not assign a static public IP address to the instance. Add an [HTTP(S) Load Balancer and enable IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/tutorial-gce#step_4_create_a_load_balancer). Add each user's identity to IAP for identity-based access control.

Additional methods suitable for developers:

1. My favorite is to use [WireGuard](https://wireguard.how/server/google-cloud-platform/) (VPN) and use peer-based access control.